# How to equally space empty divs with CSS only in flex?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So I have a structure pretty similar to the snippet below. 
The issue I have is that I am trying to make it so that the divs such as `child` always take the same height relative to the container even if they are empty. So if there are two children they have to be 50% of the parent if there are three children 33.3% of the parent and ec.
Did a lot of digging, tried using`flex-grow` and setting it on the children, adding an `after` content on the childContent class if it was empty but the empty children still collapse.
Is it even possible to achieve equal heights on the children without using js and fixed heights and if yes how?

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.child {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.childHeader {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.headerItem {
  background-color: red;
}

.childContent {
  background-color: white;
}

.childContent:empty:after {
  content: '.';
  visibility: hidden;
  min-height: 300px;
}

.contentItem {
  background-color: skyblue;
  border: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="childHeader">
      <div class="headerItem">1</div>
      <div class="headerItem">2</div>
      <div class="headerItem">3</div>
      <div class="headerItem">4</div>
      <div class="headerItem">5</div>
      <div class="headerItem">6</div>
      <div class="headerItem">7</div>
    </div>
    <div class="childContent">
      <div class="contentItem">1</div>
      <div class="contentItem">2</div>
      <div class="contentItem">3</div>
      <div class="contentItem">4</div>
      <div class="contentItem">5</div>
      <div class="contentItem">6</div>
      <div class="contentItem">7</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="childHeader">
      <div class="headerItem">1</div>
      <div class="headerItem">2</div>
      <div class="headerItem">3</div>
      <div class="headerItem">4</div>
      <div class="headerItem">5</div>
      <div class="headerItem">6</div>
      <div class="headerItem">7</div>
    </div>
    <div class="childContent">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="childHeader">
      <div class="headerItem">1</div>
      <div class="headerItem">2</div>
      <div class="headerItem">3</div>
      <div class="headerItem">4</div>
      <div class="headerItem">5</div>
      <div class="headerItem">6</div>
      <div class="headerItem">7</div>
    </div>
    <div class="childContent">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you want to expand the one with the `red` background?

Comment: @indefinite No the `child-content` div, the one with the white background.

Comment: But you don't have a fixed height on the `.child` element, so how can it's children (namely `.childContent`) have any kind of percentile height? Also, you want to display a flex column of `.child` elements, where each element has the same height as the `.container`. That makes no sense, because you try to do the math 100% + 100% + 100% = 100% (.child + .child + .child = .container).

Answer (score 0):

Check this out, I'm not really sure if this is what you want to do.

 I just added `min-height: calc(100vh - 60px);` in your `.childContent`

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.child {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.childHeader {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.headerItem {
  display:flex;
  flex-basis:100%;
  background-color: red;
}

.childContent {
  background-color: grey;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  min-height: calc(80vh - 60px);
}

.childContent:empty::after {
  content: '.';
  visibility: hidden;
  
}

.contentItem {
  background-color: skyblue;
  border: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="childHeader">
      <div class="headerItem">1</div>
      <div class="headerItem">2</div>
      <div class="headerItem">3</div>
      <div class="headerItem">4</div>
      <div class="headerItem">5</div>
      <div class="headerItem">6</div>
      <div class="headerItem">7</div>
    </div>
    <div class="childContent">
      <div class="contentItem">1</div>
      <div class="contentItem">2</div>
      <div class="contentItem">3</div>
      <div class="contentItem">4</div>
      <div class="contentItem">5</div>
      <div class="contentItem">6</div>
      <div class="contentItem">7</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="childHeader">
      <div class="headerItem">1</div>
      <div class="headerItem">2</div>
      <div class="headerItem">3</div>
      <div class="headerItem">4</div>
      <div class="headerItem">5</div>
      <div class="headerItem">6</div>
      <div class="headerItem">7</div>
    </div>
    <div class="childContent">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="childHeader">
      <div class="headerItem">1</div>
      <div class="headerItem">2</div>
      <div class="headerItem">3</div>
      <div class="headerItem">4</div>
      <div class="headerItem">5</div>
      <div class="headerItem">6</div>
      <div class="headerItem">7</div>
    </div>
    <div class="childContent">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Check this one out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc